# Implement a graceful failure process for web links for a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, http-headers

I am writing a `JSP` web app that has a number of external web links. I am trying to write a `Java class` that will take in the `HTTP response` code from the external web link and if the website is unavailable display a meaningful message to the user.

My working class to output the `HTTP response` code to the JSP:

```
public class httpResponseUtility {

 public int urlResponse (int respCode) throws IOException {

  HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;

  URL calUrl  = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk/400"); //Replace with URL string

  try {
     urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) calUrl.openConnection();
     urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     urlConn.connect();

     respCode = urlConn.getResponseCode(); 
  } 
  catch (IOException e) { 
     urlConn.disconnect();
  }
 return respCode;
 } 
}
```

However, instead of defining the external URL in the URL calUrl line - (the google link is for verification that the response passes back to the JSP) - I would like to pass in one of any of the other external links defined in the JSP and then pass the 'HTTP Response' back to the main JSP to call a separate error handling jsp.

My issue is: how do I pass in each web link as a param to the class (or even can I) - or am I approaching the problem in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: You need to take a few steps back.  There exists a JSP page that for whatever reason you want to display multiple links.  Before that page loads you want to check the response code of each link.  If it's not a 2xx code you want to replace it with something else, if it is a 2xx code you want to keep the link as is.  Am I reading this correct?  You don't explain when you want to check if those links are working (when clicked, when page loads, etc).  You don't explain if there is one or more than one link per page, etc.  If you define this more I can help

Comment: Yes that is correct - I have a main JSP which has around seven web links that go to seven separate websites. I want to display a suitable error page when the user clicks on any one of the seven web links,  if anything other than a 2xx response, is received from that link.  Is that any clearer?

Comment: Wait, once the user clicks the link, does he leave your website, or do you use some terrible UI like an iframe?

Comment: If he leaves your website, I think this would be better done with JS or another client-side language : 1) it's not because your server can access a website that the user can 2) it would make it easier to implement the better UX that would be displaying a status next to the link so that the user doesn't need to click it to know what will happen (plus a refresh loop with AJAX if the user is expected to sit on the page for some time) 3) less bandwidth use for your server. In this case use `HEAD` requests rather than `GET`

Comment: No - not using iframes. And the external websites are part of a large educational domain in which by JSP web app sits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Frontend code

Your html links would look something like this.

```
<a href="/OutboundHttpServlet?url=http://outboundsiteone.com">http://outboundsiteone.com</a>
```

The user believes they are going to `http://outboundsiteone.com` but they are actually just sending that URL to the servlet.

#### Backend code

```
@WebServlet("/OutboundHttpServlet")
public class OutboundHttpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public OutboundHttpServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uri = request.getParameter("url");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        int code = getCode(uri);

        if(code >= 200 && code <= 299) {
            response.setHeader("Location", uri);
        }

        response.setHeader("Location", new String("yourerrorpage.jsp"));
    }

     public int getCode(String uri) throws IOException {

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          int response = -1;
          URL url  = new URL(uri); 

          try {
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
             conn.connect();

             response = conn.getResponseCode(); 
          } catch (IOException e) { 
             conn.disconnect();
          }

         return response;
     } 
}
```

Backend code basically just checks the error status code of the url the user wishes to go to.  If it is successful they are forwarded there.  If there is an error they are forwarded to your error page.  You could also jsut forward back to your previous page and send an error message in the response - and then show the response in place of the link.